# Question about regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm parsing a text file and I need to remove all terms such this:

```
upcoming:event=103499
abc:dfe=123813
...

Format: `term1:term=0000000`
```

I'm currently using this reg expression to remove such terms from my text file:

```
   myString = myString.replaceAll("[0-9A-Za-z]+:[0-9A-Za-z]+", "");
```

So for example, if I have a string like this:

```
"blabla abc:dfe=123813 cococo ghi:pol=09339 pppoooo"
```

it should become: `"blabla cococo pppoooo"`

But it doesn't work

thanks

Comment: Provide field[i] and HOW it does not work, please. What is the "  , " at the start of the regex for?

Comment: Do you want to remove the text before the '=' sign? As in, `upcoming:event=103499` should become `=103499`?

Comment: @Ingo I've fixed it. @Mauritz Hansen I want to remove it, delete it the entire string

Comment: @R0MANARMY It just remains there, and I want to delete it instead.

Comment: You can't. Strings are immutable.

Comment: Comments removed, in the future, please state what the expected behavior is and what the actual behavior is.  It makes it much easier for people to answer the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of `replaceAll` back to the string reference:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[0-9A-Za-z]+:[0-9A-Za-z]+", "");
```

[**And it works**](http://www.ideone.com/lurcK)

But if you want to replace the entire string you can do:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[0-9A-Za-z]+:[0-9A-Za-z=]+", "");
```

EDIT:

For the edited question you can use:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("[0-9A-Za-z]+:[0-9A-Za-z]+=[0-9]+ ?", "");
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/MAfrF)

Comment: Hi Cod, "=" won't work inside the bracket. You will have to put that after the + sign.

Comment: @Code: If you note there is no response after the code run. Before: upcoming:event=103499 After:

Comment: I've updated my question, sorry. Consider that the string is composed by multiple terms and I need to remove only the ones with the given format.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
myString=myString.replaceAll("[0-9A-Za-z]+:[0-9A-Za-z]+=", "");
```

I you would like to keep `=` then remove from the reg exp string above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by codeaddict works correctly to meet your requirements, with the exception that it will maintain the extra spaces caused by the removal of the content.  The following logic removes the spaces as well:

```
String myString = "blabla abc:dfe=123813 cococo ghi:pol=09339 pppoooo";
// assumes that the string does not start with ' '
myString = myString.replaceAll("[0-9A-Za-z]+:[0-9A-Za-z=]+\\ ?", "");
// myString is now equal to "blabla cococo pppoooo" as per your edit.
```